# How to use mathematical induction to verify: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: induction

How to use mathematical induction to verify: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

I have already tried it myself: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONOYp.jpg)

but it is just not working out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's all correct except your hypothesis in c) should just be $ \frac{k+1}{k+2} $

Comment: Try partial fraction decomposition on the summand

Comment: @WW1 Thanks! but how would that work? I must be adding the wrong equation in step C the right?

Comment: @WW1 after a reviewing a problem worked over in class I think I was calculating C incorrectly. If I now understand correctly C is $\frac{k+1}{k+2}$ like you said. The mistake was adding $\frac{k}{k+1}$. Right? Thanks!

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.  Please don't use external images as links to external image servers are not stable.  Please use SE's built-in image-uploading functionality

Comment: Not sure if you bothered to check but the image is over the size limit. If you want to transcribe the image's work for me be my guest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base Step:- If $n=1$, then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{1}{1(1+1)}=\frac12$$
and
$$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac12$$
Since $n=k$,the base step is true.

Inductive Hypothesis:- Assume $P(k)$ is true.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{k}{(k+1)}$$

Now show that $P(k+1)$ is true
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{k+1}{k+1+1}=\frac{k+1}{k+2}$$

Now,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} =\sum_{i=k}^{k}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}+\frac{1}{k+1(k+2)}$$
$$=\frac{k}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+1(k+2)}$$
$$=\frac{k^2+2k+1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$
$$=\frac{(k+1)^2}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$
$$=\frac{k+1}{k+2}$$
Therefore, $p(k+1)$ is true.

By the principle of mathematical induction $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Comment: Thanks, this along with @WW1's comment really helped clear things up! The way my math teacher explained the problem, breaking it down it little bits ended up being more confusing than just working it out in one go. Thanks!

Comment: I added the base step now.

Comment: Thank you, and +1

Answer (score 3):

For n=1:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{1}\frac{1}{i\left(i+1\right)}&=\frac{1}{1(1+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{n}{n+1}&=\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$
hence proved for n=1.

Assume it holds true for n=k, where k is any natural number. Therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{i\left(i+1\right)}&=\frac{k}{k+1}\\
\end{align}
$$
Hence inducing that for $k=k+1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i\left(i+1\right)}&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{i\left(i+1\right)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&=\frac{k}{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&=\frac{k(k+2)+1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&=\frac{k^2+2k+1}{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)^2}{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)}{(k+1)+1}
\end{align}
$$
and then write a conclusion :)